# get all images in an HTML string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm always having trouble with that,
i'm loading a file with AJAX :

```
$.ajax({
    url: fullHref,
    success : function(result) {
        console.log(fullHref+" was loaded via AJAX");
        saveImages(result);
    }
});
```

and trying to iterate through all images in `result` :

```
function saveImages(file){
    console.log("savesImages enterd");
    $(file).find('img').each(function(){
        console.log("The file has this image : "+$(this).attr('src'));
    });
}
}
```

I've also tried :

- `$('img',file)`
- `$('img',$(file))`
- `$('img',$(file).html())`

Yet it doesn't enter the loop.

Any suggestions?
I'm using Chrome, and i **don't** wanna use regex.

Comment: sorry forgot to copy the function declartion

Comment: You're sure that `file` contains (valid) HTML?

Comment: Are you getting expected string back from AJAX call?

Comment: @Blowsie seriously? regex is the right tool if you have the best HTML parser at your disposal?

Comment: yes jack and @Blowsie because it seems to be easier to maintain with jQuery because i have other manipulations on those images.

Comment: Can you give us sample output for `file` ?

Comment: well it doesn't for me with the output i've posted (using Chrome) maybe the fact that it's a full html page matters.

Comment: @eric.itzhak I still dont see sample HTML that gets downloaded into `result`.

Comment: @tomdemuyt Oh sorry i deleted it as the problem was solved so this will appeal to more future visitor, thanks for  your intention to help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try`filter()` instead of find:

```
$(file).filter('img').each(function() { /* ... */ });
```

`find()` looks down the DOM tree which is not what you want if the `img` elements in the string are all at the root level.

Comment: Well this explains alot.. thank you Rory this did enter the loop!

Comment: @Blowsie how about you fix the syntax error in your fiddle then try it again before trying to argue against me? Actually allow me: http://jsfiddle.net/kvgUH/3/

Comment: it doesn't for me, i believe it has something to do with the fact that my output is a full html. say @RoryMcCrossan you know what will happen if img is not a valid tag? if it has a syntex error? as i don't have control over the html file.

Comment: What is the syntax error? So long as it is still an `img` tag and has a `src` attribute it should still work.

Comment: i meant mostly about ending `/>` tags but your answer is sufficient, thanks again.

Comment: Interesting. Guess the behaviour is different with full html vs fragment :) +1

Answer (score 2):

Just make a new node and set the `innerHTML` of it.

```
$('<span></span>').html(file).find('img').each(...
```